# Switch vs Classes for flow control in PHP

Tags: php, oop, control-flow, procedural-programming

Recently, I wrote a simple web application.
I currently have.

- A static page which serves the html markup and the resources I need
- A javascript routing handling mechanism which communicate with the server and render responses on the client.

For each object I need to manipulate, the server provides a php script at `/app/object.php` which accepts POST data and return JSON results.

Eg (not actual responses):

```
POST /app/comments.php?a=add&page_id=43&author=A&text=Some%20Text
{"s":"OK"}

POST /app/comments.php?a=list&page_id=43
[{ "author": 'A', "text": "Some text"}, { "author": "B", "text": "Other text"}]

POST /app/users.php?a=list
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Under the hood the JSON api is implemented like that:

```
//comments.php
require('init.php'); 
// start sessions, open database connections with data in config.php

switch(POST('a')){
case "list":
    //.... retrieving data
    echo json_encode($data)
break;
case "add":
    //.... inserting data
    echo '{"s":"OK"}';
break;
}
```

The largest object has 7 methods and 200 (well-indented, not compressed) LOC, while the average is roughly 3 methods per object.

A developer friend of mine is suggesting to replace the switch with objects, to make it "simpler", "more extensible" and "more maintainable".

I frankly don't see how a system like that could get any simpler (especially by using objects) but I'd love to know other developers' opinions.

Ignoring the performance hit of using objects in PHP, should I use a class-based approach?

**If yes**, how can I structure my JSON API in order to use objects, without adding too much code (and thus decreasing the maintainability of the project)?

Comment: I don't, really. It just how I've always done things, since older PHP versions. Just the more "natural" way to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

class Controller {
  protected $post;
  public function __construct() {
     $this->post = $post;
  }
  public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    if(!method_exists($this, $name)) {
      die("Unknown action!");
    }
  }
  public function whatever() {
    echo json_encode($this->post['page_id']);
  }
  public function data() {
    echo '{"s":"OK"}';
  }
  // new action? just add another method
}


$controller = new Controller();
$controller->{$_POST('a')}(); // example 1

$controller->data(); // you can't do it using switch
```

1. Easy to add new methods
2. Easy to maintance
3. You can fire your methods whenever your want
4. Code is tidy
5. It's really common practice

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I still don't see particular advantages, just slightly longer syntax and I don't see how this may be any harder or easier to maintain or extend. 

I suppose that answers my question, but I really would like to know some reasons, other than "OOP is better because it's better".

I think I'll switch to using classes, looks like that's what is hot on the market and speaking the same language with the rest of the team is important.